# How do i solve most frequent word in sentence according to these hints in python?

Tags: python

I did this code but its not perfect because it returns the key with highest value but does not return the one that comes first alphabetically. How would I make it return the one that is first in alphabet?
Also, I was supposed to do it according to the hints but I did it differently. How would I do it according to the hints?

> Complete the most_frequent() function below so that it returns the most frequently occurring word in a given string.
>
> For example, if the input s is s = 'I scream you scream we all scream for ice cream', the result should be scream as it is the most frequent word in this sentence.
>
> If there is a tie for the most common word, return only one result, the first (tied) word in alphabetical order.

```
"""Quiz: Most Frequent Word"""

def most_frequent(s):
    """Return the most frequently occuring word in s."""
    
    # HINT: Use the built-in split() function to transform the string s into an
    #       array
    words = s.split(" ")
    
    # HINT: Sort the new array by using the built-in sorted() function or
    #       .sort() list method
 
    # HINT: Iterate through the array and count each occurance of every word
    #       using the .count() list method
  
    dict = {}
    for word in words:
        dict[word] = words.count(word)
       
 

    # HINT: Find the number of times the most common word appears using max()
    result = max(dict, key=dict.get)

    # HINT: Locate the index of the most frequently seen word
    
    # HINT: Return the most frequent word. Remember that if there is a tie,
    #       return the first (tied) word in alphabetical order.

    
    return result



def test_run():
    """Test most_frequent() with some inputs."""
    print(most_frequent("cat bat mat mat cat")) # output: 'cat'
    print(most_frequent("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter")) # output: 'butter'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

Comment: I would look at `collections.Counter`, it already has a most_common method.

Comment: `dict` is a key word in Python I think, so you should probably use a different variable like `word_counts`.

Comment: If you want to do it the plane dictionary way as you are, then you can sort the words using `words.sort()`, which sorts them in place - no return value.  Then go through the words and check if the corresponding dictionary value matches the max that you already got.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use key argument in `sorted`. Sorting on the basis of frequencies(values) from highest to lowest first then sorting the tuples according to keys in lex order

```
s='cat bat mat mat cat'
words = s.split(" ")
d={}
for i in words:
    d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1
sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]),reverse=False)[0][0]  #'cat'
```

If you want to use Counter from collections just to reduce some lines of code

```
from collections import Counter
s='cat bat mat mat cat'
words = s.split(" ")
d=Counter(words)
sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]),reverse=False)[0][0]  #'cat'
```

`reverse=False` is optional

Answer (score 0):

A not-cool-at-all solution:

```
s = 'I scream you scream we all scream for ice cream all'
d = dict()
for word in s.split(' '):
    if word in d:
        d[word] += 1
    else:
        d[word] = 0
k = sorted(list(d.items()), key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
highest_freq = k[-1][1]
result = k[-1][0]
for i in reversed(range(len(k))):
    if k[i][1] < highest_freq:
        break
    else:
        result = k[i][0]
print(result)
```